# Magento Category Path Url Structure

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I am migrating a Magento installation from 1.7 to 1.9. In the (old) 1.7 installation, URL's are structured as follows:

**Category:**

```
www.webstore.com/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category
```

**Product:**

```
www.webstore.com/product.html
```

I am unable to replicate this url structure in the new installation as the configuration setting in 
**`System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations`** only allows to turn on or off the category path for products, but I only want to turn it on for the category url path.

Is there a setting, I am overlooking or is it be necessary to change the catalog rewrite generation code and if so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go to admin > catalog > URL Rewrite Management and set there the URL structure you need. The downside is that you'll need to add a rule for each category/product and for any new ones in the future.